# How do I view graphs created using NetworkX library without Anaconda/Spyder?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am doing a Discrete Maths course. Students are supposed to use the `NetworkX` library for visualising graphs. The instructors and TAs are using Spyder and Anaconda. And I have no plans of using them.
I am not being able to view graphs created by the NetworkX library. The rest of the code work perfectly.
Here's a sample:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(1, 6):
    G.add_node(i)

G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(4, 5)
G.add_edge(1, 6)

print(G.nodes())
print(G.edges())

nx.draw(G)
```

And here's the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[(1, 2), (1, 6), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

So the last line is not printing. Changing it to `print(nx.draw(G))` just adds a `None` at the end of the output.
I have tried using Geany, VS Code and the terminal (Bash), but cannot see the graph. What do I do?

How would I be able to view graphs without using Anaconda/Spyder?

Comment: Here's the video I am following- https://youtu.be/B2K_x5ZX_eU?t=359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by viewing the graph as external images. When a graph is generated, it can be viewed as an image on a different window, or it can be saved to the current directory.

A submodule called `pyplot` from the package `matplotlib` is needed to be imported to do this.

Suppose a graph is drawn using `nx.draw(graph-name)`. In Spyder, it will output a graph automatically. But that doesn't happen in terminal.

We can view the generated graph using the command `plt.show()`. Where we have imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`.

`plt.show()` will display the graph in a different window, but it will not save a copy of the graph.

If you want to save a copy of the graph in the current directory, use `plt.savefig('file-with-extension')`. It will save a copy of the graph.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> G = nx.graph()
>>> nx.add_path(G, [0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> nx.draw(G, with_labels=1)
>>> plt.show()
```

in the interpreter will give you this-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib, you just have to set the parameters on nx.draw to the axes of the matplotlib figure, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_graph(nx_graph):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=72)
    nx.draw(nx_graph, pos=nx.spring_layout(nx_graph), ax=axes, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

The networkx docs recommend using more specific dedicated tools for graph visualization, but this works for the basics. See:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html